# runOnUiThread Undefined for Class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dialog

I'm trying to throw and alert dialog on the UI thread from my background thread but I'm having problems with runOnUiThread being undefined. I have tried `FindLocation.this.runOnUiThread` and runOnUiThread but both seem to throw the same error `The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type new LocationListener(){}` (or `...the type FindLocation`). Any ideas why? Here is a snippet of my FindLocation.java class. This is called by my main activity.

```
public class FindLocation extends Thread {

public boolean inJurisdiction;
public boolean AlertNotice = false;
private LocationManager locManager;
private LocationListener locListener;

Context ctx;
public String userId;

public FindLocation(Context ctx) {
     this.ctx = ctx;
}

 public void start(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        super.start();

      }

@Override
public void run() {
     Looper.prepare();
    final String usr = userId;  

    //get a reference to the LocationManager
    locManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //checked to receive updates from the position
    locListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            String lat = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()); 
            String lon = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());

            Double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            Double longitude = loc.getLongitude();

            if (latitude >= 39.15296 && longitude >= -86.547546 && latitude <= 39.184901 && longitude <= -86.504288 || inJurisdiction != false) {
                Log.i("Test", "Yes");  

                inJurisdiction = true;

                FindLocation.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { ///****error here****
                    public void run() {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                        alert.setTitle("Sent");
                        alert.setMessage("You will be contacted shortly.");
                        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: that's because `runOnUiThread` is method of `android.app.Activity`, not `java.lang.Thread`

Comment: Shoot. Is there a way to implement something similar?

Comment: @MartinSykes nope, [it doesn't](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Comment: @Martin Sykes please remove that comment.. it is misleading as Context has no access to runOnUIThread()

Comment: ctx will have runOnUiThread if its an instance of an Activity. To be more clear then my previous comment.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since `runOnUIThread()` is method of `Activity`, you can pass reference to calling activity in constructor.

```
...
Context ctx;
Activity act;
public String userId;
...

public FindLocation(Context ctx, Activity act) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.act = act;
}
```

and use `runOnUIThread()` like

```
act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...});
```

However I believe it's unsafe and you need to take precautions to make sure your Activity is still there when you are calling `runOnUiThread`

Comment: Ok, I can get this implemented without errors in eclipse, but when I run it, I get a NullPointerException error on the `act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...});` line(s). Why would this happen? Could it have something to do with my looper?

Comment: try to find out what actually is `null`, by adding `Log.d("Test" + "" + act);` before `act.runOnUiThread()` - if it's not `act`, then problem is somewhere within your `Runnable`

Comment: I just found it, I think. When I start the thread from my Main Activity, I use this statement: `new FindLocation(getBaseContext(), null).start(usr_id1);` I'm not sure what to pass instead of null. Any ideas? I tried `this` and `MainActivity` but neither work.

Comment: Yeah, it's right where there problem is. If you call it from activity itself, this should work with `this`. If the call is from inner class, `MainActivity.this` should work.

Comment: To get the activity, you can use `getActivity().runOnUiThread(...`.

Answer (score 15):

```
Another better approach..
```

**No need to create constructor for getting Activity.**

Just typecast the context to Activity class.

```
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        { 
             Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is throwing exception in my case :java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: I found this for the solution of my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23324440/2223942.
Still is there any ways to use your way successfully ? @Nepster

Answer (score 4):

`runOnUIThread()` is a method belonging to `Activity`.. SO you cannot call it from a Thread.

So instead of Context take Activity instance in its Constructor and call it using that.. something like

```
activity.runOnUIThread();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a neater and more modular way of doing this. For this you need to have defined an `Application Context`. Once you have that, you can call `RunOnUIThread` from any class library without the mess of having a reference to the `Activity`.

From anywhere within your class library call:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Application.Context.MainLooper);
handler.Post(() => doStuff());
```

Please bear in mind that this is written in C# as I use MonoDroid, but I believe it is very similar to Java. 
For how to create an ApplicationContext look at this [thread](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Custom-Application-class-to-store-global-variables-java-runtime-ClassNotFoundException-td4383621.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your class to include Activity
Like this

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {}
```

This will make 'runOnUiThread' available.

Also remember to import Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

Answer (score 0):

### I also Experience this yesterday while handling Java Socket.

#### 1. Pass your Activity to the FindLocation constructor

```java
Activity activity;

public FindLocation(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Then use the activity object to call runOnUIThread()

```java
this.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    ...
});
```